# Check Linux service status and start it if stopped using a Python script

Tags: python, linux

I have a fixed list of services in a Linux server. I want to check the status of these services and start the service if it's stopped.  I'm able to get this done using a shell script, but I'm looking for a Python script to do this.

Comment: You should use the process manager (e.g. `systemd`, `upstart`, `sysv`) to do these stuffs; it's their job.

Comment: Iterate through the service names and then check `systemctl is-active <service>`. If it is `inactive`, then `start` the service ?

Comment: Agreed, you should use shell script for this task or tools like `ansible`, not Python.

Comment: Do you have `svcadm` on your machine?

Comment: @heemayl  I'm a newbie and trying to learn stuff.  Any specific reason why it shell script and not Python?

Comment: @Dominique - No.  We don't.

Comment: @gotviseryon I didn't say to use any shell/python script. I said that you should leave this to the process manager to do the job for you automatically rather than you doing it via manual scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `subprocess.Popen` or `os.system`.

Example:

`subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "service", "redis", "start"])`

`subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "service", "redis", "status"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

You can read the stdout and check if the process is stopped and also see the exist status.

Alternatively you can use [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to monitor processes.